# Enable wire logging in WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I can't see an option in Carbon Console to enable wire logging, nor any logging at all. Is there an option to enable it via a configuration file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI does not support this in APIM v3. But you can achieve this by changing the configurations as below.

1. Open the log4j2.properties file in APIM_HOME/repository/conf location.
2. Search for "loggers =".
3. At the end of that line, add "synapse-wire" as a logger. Use comma (,) before the synapse-wire as loggers are separated by commas.
4. No need to restart. log4j2 is implemented as hot deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to restart the server after adding the above entry to the log4j2.properties file as in step 4. 
You just need to add it and save it. It will be hot deployed and you ll be able to see a log line similar to following once it is hot deployed.

[2020-01-08 13:25:25,604]  INFO - LoggingUpdaterServiceComponent Logging configuration applied successfully

Above means, the change you did, reflected properly. So you are good to go ahead.